# Do trees grow back the The Oregon Trail: American Settler?

Tags: android, the-oregon-trail-american-settler

On [The Oregon Trail: American Settler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftTOHM&hl=en), for Android, do trees eventually grow back after you've chopped them down?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't settling down completley destroy the concept of Oregon Trail?

Comment: @Emerica. haha to be honest I thought the same

Comment: It acctually looks kind of fun though for a mobile game. As long as people can still get dissentery I am in for a try.

Comment: @Emerica. Looks like this is a sequel to Oregon Trail. The settler game is at the end of the trail when they have arrived and are now settling in the new land. Makes more sense now :)

Comment: @Curt looks more like they were trying to attract attention to their game by naming it after a very popular childhood game. =p

Comment: @Decency GameLoft also made Oregon Trail http://www.gameloft.com/mobile-games/the-oregon-trail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this link](http://forum.gameloft.com/index.php?topic=45479.45) which has some interesting information on this issue.

The generally gist seems to be that you need to keep the game running in the foreground for either saplings and/or partial tress to regrow. The rate is claimed to be around 1/7 per hour.

Personally this does seem like a bug to me, but I guess you also have to consider the fact that is take 7 energy to remove a tree. If the grow back while you were offline, this might prove time consuming just to clear a small area a trees when you consider the energy cap (especially so soon in the game)... then again, if you plant a sapling you clearly want a tree to grow there anyway.

Bad design or a bug? I guess time will tell

Comment: Pretty certain that this is a bug. I restored my phone to factory settings ( losing level 83 on OS :( ) and tried planting saplings. My trees have started growing at a rate of about 2/7 per week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it takes really a very long time

Comment: Cheers, do you know roughly how long it takes?

Answer (score 0):

Trees that were originally spawned into the world do not grow back at any point from what Ive experienced. Even if you dont cut them down to a stump. Sapplings that are planted do grow relatively fast enough to generate wood. Im currently experimenting with the dipperent types of sapplings.